# How to install annotator from elementary OS appcenter in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, ppa, flatpak

[Annotator](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.phase1geo.annotator/) is a lightweight application for annotating images. It is much simpler and faster to edit an image in annotator than in GIMP.

It was recently featured in [OMG! Ubuntu!](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/10/best-annotation-tool-for-linux-desktop).
How to install it in Ubuntu?

[image: annotator]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several ways to install Annotator. Parts of this answer are from the project's [README](https://github.com/phase1geo/Annotator/) (and parts of the README were updated from this answer).

---

### PPA

You can use the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/annotator/) maintained by Panda Jim (who also happens to maintain the GIMP PPA, among many others).  Enter the following commands one by one

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/annotator
sudo apt update
sudo apt install com.github.phase1geo.annotator
```

The PPA supports Ubuntu 20.04+.

### Flatpak

You can use flatpak to download it from the Elementary appcenter repositories.

```
flatpak install https://flatpak.elementary.io/repo/appstream/com.github.phase1geo.annotator.flatpakref
```

### Manually install from source

First install the dependencies.

```
sudo apt install meson valac debhelper gobject-2.0 glib-2.0 libgee-0.8-dev libgranite-dev libxml2-dev libgtk-3-dev libhandy-1-dev
```

(libhandy for Ubuntu 20.04 is available in [this](https://launchpad.net/%7Eapandada1/+archive/ubuntu/libhandy-1) PPA. In later versions of Ubuntu, it is available in the official repositories.)

Then download the source and run the install script.

```
git clone https://github.com/phase1geo/Annotator.git --depth=1
cd Annotator
./app install
```

### Flatpak (manual install)

Download the source, and manually build and install with flatpak (the software is not yet available on flathub).

```
git clone https://github.com/phase1geo/Annotator.git --depth=1
cd Annotator
./app flatpak
```

And you can open the app from menu (or run it with `flatpak run com.github.phase1geo.annotator`).

Comment: Also you can install it as Flatpak by some new way - `flatpak install https://flatpak.elementary.io/repo/appstream/com.github.phase1geo.annotator.flatpakref` (the link is shown on [*Download as Flatpak* button here](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.phase1geo.annotator/)). As a free bonus it will add https://flatpak.elementary.io/repo as new remote origin with about 125 apps from [Elementary's AppCenter](https://appcenter.elementary.io/). Good finding!

Comment: Thank you @N0rbert.